# https request to localhost is blocked by ios simulator (react native)

Tags: react-native, networking, localhost, ios-simulator, fetch-api

I know that ios blocks cleartext request eg (http).
But i have a localhost https server running with a (self signed certificate).

Now i keep getting the error

> [TypeError: Network request failed]

I have tried different solutions from stack overflow like changing the url from
`https://localhost:3000/app/` to `https://127.0.0.1:3000/app/` or to use my local ip eg `https://10.20.200.50:3000/app/`

But non seem to work.
Is the only option i have to whitelist my localhost url in the info.plist file? I would like to avoid this option since it seems like a weak hacky solution...

After checking the Info.plist file i noticed it is already in there..

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

And yet i still get the same error....

Fyi requests to an external api like `https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity` work fine.

So to summarize: How do i make an fetch request to a https localhost server from the ios simulator.

Comment: The IP address always work, are you sure you're using the correct IP address?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `ifconfig | grep inet` in a terminal and locate an address like `192.168.x.x`

[image]

2. Try using the above IP in the fetch URL.
3. If still not working make sure your server is available when you access it with any browser locally at `https://<IP>:3000/testendpoint` or using CURL or using a tool like POSTMAN.
4. Make sure your headers like `Content-Type` header are set correctly:

```
    Accept: 'application/json',  //<----
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', //<---
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'val1',
    secondParam: 'val2',
  }),
```

As a last possible solution if none of the above work restart the metro server and the simulator.

Answer (score -1):

there can be multiple issues with it.

- if your localhost running on the same machine.
- check the iOS simulator has connected to internet. sometime the iOS simulator is not connected to the internet.
- there is another solution that it [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) . use this. it is a great tool

Comment: as mentioned in my question, the ios simulator is connected to the internet because a api call to `https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity` works. 
And yes my localhost is running on the same machine, but under a different port so this should work as far as i am aware. 
Ngrok is great, but would like to avoid it since it adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: on which port your server is running

Comment: locahost server is running on port 3000

Comment: did you access server in postman

Comment: never used postman, but i use the rest client in vscode and that works perfectly fine. I can also access my localhost from the browser without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the configuration in the Info.plist file to tell ATS to allow HTTP connections to localhost?

I'm just not sure what the impact will be when moving from dev to production

thinking something like this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're facing issues with making HTTP requests to localhost from an iOS Simulator when developing a React Native application, it's likely due to security restrictions imposed by iOS.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

- Use your machine's IP address instead of localhost:
- Find your machine's IP address by running the command ipconfig
  getifaddr en0 (for macOS) or ipconfig (for Windows) in the terminal.
  Replace localhost in your code with the IP address you obtained.
  Allow insecure HTTP connections:
- In your app's Info.plist file, add the following key-value pair:

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

**This change allows your app to make HTTP requests without the need for secure HTTPS connections.**